# Can not write to AOF

Tags: .net-core, redis, windows-server-2016

I am using **Redis 4.0.2.3** on **Windows server**.
I have application that writes to Redis cluster **4** masters and **4** salves, everything was working fine until yesterday i noticed the following error:

> MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: Unknown error

Any ideas?

Comment: "Cannot allocate memory" .do you have enough memory?

Comment: @AminGolmahalle maxmemory 31250000kb
I think i have enough

Comment: Did you restart the redis server after the error occurred?

Comment: No, why would i do that?

Comment: because the cause of the error is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized redis server in read-only mode. Reboot it with Read/Write mode